# sql select FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp) engine independent

Tags: sql, datetime, select, unix-timestamp

I need to convert INT to DATETIME, on SQL Server it would be:

```
select cast(convert(unix_timestamp,103) AS datetime)
```

on MySQL the syntax is:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp)
```

But i need to make it engine independent(SQL Server, MySQL, T-sql and so on).
is it possible?

Maybe its possible to trick it in PHP?

```
<?php
$sql='select cast(convert(1350134926,103) AS datetime)';
$result = @mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result){
  $sql=' select FROM_UNIXTIME(1350134926)';
  $result = @mysql_query($sql);

  if(!$result){...}

}

?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to depend on the DBMS, why not move the conversion client side

Comment: PHP has a function that converts unix timestamps into human-readable dates: [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), why not just use that?

Comment: because 'unix_timestamp' is stored in table's column and i have to: select MONTH(cast(convert(timeColumn,103) AS datetime)) from table

Comment: @Mar And why do you have to select that?

Comment: "to make it engine independent" don't use sql, use php, otherwise the answer is "no, it can't be done". Temporal data handling is amongst the most variable across the dbms.